# How to resolve this select2 appearance problem? (working with BootStrap 4 and Laravel framework)

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, jquery-select2, laravel-mix

I'm learning Laravel framework and I wanted to add Select2 to my project with Laravel-mix. After many hours of trying to do that, I did it and everything seems to work fine, except one little, but very annoying issue.

When I click on my `<select>`, the search input inside is not focused, so it looks like that:

[image]

Okay, that not so bad, but when I click on the search input the black line flashes for less than 0,5sec:

[image]

And after that this line looks like it should (pay attention that on the first image the line was missing):

[image]

I'm not pretty sure, which lines of my code should I provide.

I used `npm i select2` command to install select2.

Then I used `composer require ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme` command to install better look for bootstrap.

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/datatables.scss', 'public/css')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.postCss('vendor/ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme/dist/select2-bootstrap4.min.css', 'public/css')
.postCss('node_modules/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css', 'public/css')
.sourceMaps();
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
try {
window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
require('bootstrap');
require('select2');


require( 'jszip' );
require( 'pdfmake' );
require( 'datatables.net-bs4' )();
require( 'datatables.net-buttons-bs4' )();
require( 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js' )();
require( 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.js' )();
require( 'datatables.net-datetime' )();
require( 'datatables.net-fixedcolumns-bs4' )();
require( 'datatables.net-fixedheader-bs4' )();
require( 'datatables.net-keytable-bs4' )();
require( 'datatables.net-responsive-bs4' )();
require( 'datatables.net-rowgroup-bs4' )();
require( 'datatables.net-rowreorder-bs4' )();
require( 'datatables.net-scroller-bs4' )();
require( 'datatables.net-searchbuilder-bs4' )();
require( 'datatables.net-searchpanes-bs4' )();
require( 'datatables.net-select-bs4' )();
} catch (e) {}
```

**app.js**

```
    jQuery(function () {
    $(".s2").select2({ theme: 'bootstrap4', focus: true });
 });
```

**app.blade.php**

```
<!-- Styles (on the head section)-->
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/datatables.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/select2.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/select2-bootstrap4.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
...
<select class="s2" style="width: 100%" name='choice' required>
    <option value="">Your choice</option>
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>
...
<!-- Scripts (at the bottom of page) -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" ></script>
```

Please help me to understand my mistake and how to fix it. I have never used any framework before, so in my other projects I just added maybe about three lines of code and everything worked well, but here I feel totally lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's weird. Solution, that worked for me was removing `theme: 'bootstrap4'` from my select2 function.

On the [GitHub page](https://github.com/ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme) the usage was described as:

```
    $('select').select2({
    theme: 'bootstrap4',
});
```

So I don't know, why it was not working and even more weird how can it work for me well without specifying the theme. It's rocket science for me.